# Getting an error using JSoup. Why?

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to login and extract data from a fantasyfootball website.

I get the following error,

> Jul 24, 2015 8:01:12 PM StatsCollector main
>   SEVERE: null
>   org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=http://fantasy.premierleague.com/
>       at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:537)
>       at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
>       at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
>       at StatsCollector.main(StatsCollector.java:26)

whenever I try this code. Where am I going wrong?

```
    public class StatsCollector {

    public static void main (String [] args){

        try {
            String url = "http://fantasy.premierleague.com/";
            Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).method(Connection.Method.GET).execute();

            Response res= Jsoup
                    .connect(url)
                    .data("ismEmail", "example@googlemail.com", "id_password", "examplepassword")
                    .method(Method.POST)
                    .execute();


            Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies();

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://fantasy.premierleague.com/transfers")
                    .cookies(loginCookies)
                    .get();

            String title = doc.title();
            System.out.println(title);
        }  

        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StatsCollector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried finding out what http status 403 means?

Comment: You should append the complete exception, not just an error message which is out of context.

Comment: i think I've done what you meant @javahippie

Comment: Its a restricted resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Response res= Jsoup
                .connect(url)
                .data("ismEmail", "example@googlemail.com", "id_password", "examplepassword")
                .method(Method.POST)
                .execute();
```

Are you trying to execute this actual code? This seems to be an example code with placeholders instead of login credentials. This would explain the error you received, [HTTP 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403).

## Edit 1

My bad. I took a look at the login form on that site, and it seems to me that you confused the `id` of the input elements ("ismEmail" and "id_password" with the `name` which gets sent with the form ("email", "password"). Is this working for you?

```
Response res= Jsoup
                .connect(url)
                .data("email", "example@googlemail.com", "password", "examplepassword")
                .method(Method.POST)
                .execute();
```

## Edit 2

Okay, this was stuck in my head, beacause signing into a website with JSoup  should not be that hard. I created an account there and tried for myself. Code first:

```
 String url = "https://users.premierleague.com/PremierUser/j_spring_security_check";

        Response res = Jsoup
                .connect(url)
                .followRedirects(false)
                .timeout(2_000)
                .data("j_username", "<USER>")
                .data("j_password", "<PASSWORD>")
                .method(Method.POST)
                .execute();

        Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies();

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://fantasy.premierleague.com/squad-selection/")
                .cookies(loginCookies)
                .get();
```

So what is happening here? First I realized, that the target of the login form was wrong. The page seems to be built on spring, so the form attributes and target use spring defaults `j_spring_security_check`, `j_username` and `j_password`. Then a read timeout occurred to me, until I set the flag `followRedirects(false)`. I can only guess why this helped, but maybe this is a protection against crawlers?

In the end i try to connect to the squad selection page, and the parsed response contains my personal view and data. This code seems to work for me, would you give it a try?

Comment: Haha, no. I'm using my actual credentials.

Comment: Not withstanding that, the webserver is >>telling<< you that you are not allowed to make that request.  Check that you are supply the right credentials the right way, and that those credentials allow you to fetch that resource.  (Also, a 403 response could be their way of saying "obey the terms of service".)

Comment: I see. I changed my code to what you said and it's still giving me a 403 error. Maybe it's telling me that I'm not allowed to make that request (like you say). Is there any work around to that?

Comment: Just a guess: Do you have any client_id or some token given wile registration ? If yes, try appending after the url split by a ? @HishamMohammed

Comment: Right now you are sending the POST request to the plain `http://fantasy.premierleague.com` page, the form targets `https://users.premierleague.com/PremierUser/redirectLogin`. Does this change anything?